# What tense to use for a dead person's permanent contributions?

Tags: tenses

Which one is correct:

1. Edison *was* the inventor of the light bulb.
2. Edison *is* the inventor of the light bulb.

When writing or speaking about Edison, it's correct to state that "he *was* an inventor", but what is correct when referring to the fact that he (still) is considered the inventor of *something*?

Option 1 (*was*) wins the Google contest by 19100 to 6, which probably answers my question. However, as a non-native English speaker, this isn't totally clear to me. As a matter of fact, I'm not certain what tense I would use in my native language (Swedish) for this construct!

Comment: If you use "Edison invented the light bulb" your temporal problem is removed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use either. The present you would use is called [Historical Present](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historical_present). It's used both in fiction and in history books, depending on your choice. These are both acceptable:

> 1. Edison was the inventor of the light bulb.
> 2. Edison is the inventor of the light bulb.

Comment: I didn't add it to the answer because I'm not sure but in Italian you could use the future tense as well, for historical events. I'm not sure this applies to English. (Some native speaker might confirm or not.)

Comment: As part of a historical narrative, yes. “In 1879, Edison will go on to patent an improved light bulb”.

Comment: @MetaEd: "In 1879, Edison **would** go on to patent an improved light bulb" sounds better to my ears. I wouldn't use the indicative unless a narrative context had been established, and I especially wouldn't use it with a specific point in time in mind. I would also prefer "*after* 1879" to "in 1879".

Comment: In English there is no future tense.

Comment: @Noah - But someday there will be.

Answer (score 1):

As other answers explain, either is correct grammatically. However, "Edison was the inventor of the light bulb" could imply to me that he is no longer the inventor! So it may be "technically the most correct" to use "is", albeit its lack of popularity.

Specifically the "was" is shorthand for "Edison was the inventor, but now he's dead", so it may depend on the context which one you really want to use.

Answer (score 0):

Just for clarity, Edison wasn't the inventor of the light bulb. Many people contributed to its development, Including Joseph Swan who demonstrated his light bulb before Edison and was Edison's main competitor. It's just that the history we are told only states this, because Edison made the better commercial success.

However as a native English speaker I would say, **"was the inventor"** but I'm not happy with this now and think **"is the inventor"** should be correct.

Answer (score -2):

Late Edison is the inventor of the light bulb is the correct usage

Comment: Please explain your reasoning... we need more than just personal opinion!

Comment: I have never heard anyone over the age of 10 use 'Late Edison' as opposed to 'the late Thomas Edison'.  It may be common in your circles, but that doesn't make it "correct".

Comment: He's known as Late Edison because, despite his many achievements, he never did manage to invent a decent alarm clock.  (Note: this is almost certainly not true.)

Comment: I would argue any deceased person, being no longer alive, is not naturally said to "be" anything, or to "exist" in the accepted sense which warrants "is". So, outside of the special case of 'historical present' (nicely described above), I would argue the natural tendency is to expect the past tense. _Insisting_ on the historical present, I believe, is narrow to the point of incorrect.